# Rendering GoogleMap by passing Div at runtime

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a function in which I am passing a div of a page where GoogleMap will be shown on page display. The Div ID is coming correctly but when GoogleMap is going to display Map, its giving below error.

```
<a data-transition="slide" onclick="showGoogleMap('AusMapDiv','#AustpaymentLocationsPage','151.209349','-33.840835')">Australia</a>


var myLatitude , myLongitude , pagediv ;
function showPosition(position) {
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
    var mapProp = { center : myCenter,  zoom : 5,   mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP   };

    var map = new google.maps.Map( pagediv , mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   position : myCenter });
    marker.setMap(map);
}

function showGoogleMap(pgdiv, locpage, logit, lati) {
    myLongitude = logit;
    myLatitude = lati;
    pagediv = pgdiv;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, function(){      
                  console.log("Error while showing GoogleMap"); });
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

    $.mobile.changePage(locpage , { transition: "slide"});
}
```

Comment: It seems you are passing in strings instead of numbers for lat/lng values. It'd be better to use parseFloat() in function LatLng() to change strings to numbers.

Comment: They are working, i tried it before giving Divs programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pgdiv` is the id of div which contains the map then the line:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( pagediv , mapProp);
```

should be changed to:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById(pagediv), mapProp);
```

Specification for `Map()` constructor:

```
Map(mapDiv:Node, opts?:MapOptions)
```

where `mapDiv` is DOM element and not id of `div` element.

Comment: Yes correct, it worked....it means Map API needs an Element , not the name of element to render image on.